# SQL Server - Want to Copy Column Data to Another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I got a column which has ie say Red, Yellow, Blue.

In the same table I got a column which i want this data from this column to go in numeric for the same row.

So say for example if Red is selected = 1, Yellow =2, Blue = 3.

This is all in same table and column currently exists.

So all in the same table, if i load data. I am looking for statement to say if Red appeared then the other column the numeric will populate in other column as 1 in the same row.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You create a "lookup" table that contains your desired references, then you `JOIN` your other data to this table:

```
colors

id | color
1  | Red
2  | Yellow
3  | Blue
```

For best practice, you should be storing your "colors" in a table like above, and your statements should be `JOIN`ing to this table.

Comment: Although this is a simple question where CASE will do, I think that your answer is better.

Comment: While StackOverflow likes to solve OP's problem, I prefer to give the OP the best practice.

Comment: As this is a one of, can anything just be inputted in to a statement to copy existing data??

Comment: @user3063073 See the `CASE` example in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
     Color,
     CASE Color
          WHEN 'Red' Then 1
          WHEN 'Yellow' Then 2
          WHEN 'Blue' Then 3
     END as ColorCode
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Works, but what if you want to keep a record of codes assigned to colors or change the code for a color ? FreshPrinceOfSO answer seems better than this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL Server try a switch case and please, no need to tag many sql flavors to get a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a (non-computed) table column for this.<sup>1</sup>

You'd be introducing a data **redundancy**, leading to possible corruption down the line, when one value is changed but other isn't. Specifically, you'd be introducing a [transitive functional dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency)<sup>2</sup> and consequently violating the [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3NF).

Either do the conversion dynamically in a VIEW...

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  COLOR VARCHAR(50) CHECK (COLOR IN ('Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue'))
);

CREATE VIEW V AS
SELECT
  *,
  CASE COLOR
    WHEN 'Red' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Yellow' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Blue' THEN 3
    END
  COLOR_CODE
FROM T;
```

...or use a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)...

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  COLOR VARCHAR(50) CHECK (COLOR IN ('Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue')),
  COLOR_CODE AS CASE COLOR
    WHEN 'Red' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Yellow' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Blue' THEN 3
    END
);
```

...or just use a plain client-side SELECT statement (though that runs a risk of different clients using different statement):

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE COLOR
    WHEN 'Red' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Yellow' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Blue' THEN 3
    END
  COLOR_CODE
FROM T;
```

This way you always know which data is "master" and which "derived", and there is no risk of de-synchronization.

BTW, if you're gonna do something like that, it's probably better to store integers and convert to strings, than the other way around.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Unless it's just an intermediary stage in some kind of data migration and you intend to eventually clean-up the redundancy. For example, you might want to extract colors to a separate table and then just reference the color code from there and making the extra column would be just one phase in that process.*

*<sup>2</sup> PK -> COLOR -> COLOR_CODE.*